# What is this deception-based party game?

Tags: identify-this-game, party

At some point in time I found the rules for a many player party game online and now I'm looking for it again. It involved two teams of players where each player is assigned two English words. Players of the same team would have words in common. The goal was to make contact with the other members of your team by finding other players with words in common with you. I think I discovered this game on the website of some indie designer. Any help finding the title or website of this game would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This description makes me think of [Linq](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/11945/linq)

[image: Back of the box]